# 1000hz Bootstrap Validator not working at all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I've tried to incorporate 1000hz's Validator on my form, but it doesn't seem to validate. I've looked through the source of the example form and associated files and can't see anything there that I haven't included.

I have spent days trying to sort this out.  I've read through this forum for similar posts but none of the answers seem to suggest I'm missing anything.

I have tried both data-toggle="validator" and jQuery initialisation.  When I ask it to validate on submit via jQuery, the console logs as going into that stage but I don't get any red input field borders or error messages.

Could someone please help?

I noticed in the example at https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ that it validates as you change focus between input fields which be ideal rather than waiting until submit.  Is this standard or does that require a custom option?  I didn't see custom options anywhere in the source code on that site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Navigation-with-Button1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Login-Form-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles-1.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="config1412/deliveries.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.js"></script>


</head>

<body>



   <div class="navbar-fixed-top navbar">
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-default action-button" role="button" href="customise.php"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-left"></i> BACK</a>
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
                        <span id="basketcount">2</span>&nbsp;<i class="icon ion-ios-cart"></i> <span id="baskettotal">&#163;10.80</span>                        <br/>
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-circle-filled"></i>
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-circle-filled"></i>
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-circle-filled"></i>
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-circle-outline"></i>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                                         <form id="sageform" role="form" data-toggle="validator"  method="post" >

                <button class="btn btn-default action-button" name="pay" onclick="" type="submit" href="#">NEXT <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i></button>                    
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:75px;">


    <input name="collectiondelivery" type="hidden" id="collectiondelivery" value=""/>
                    <input name="customerpostcode" type="hidden" id="customerpostcode" value=""/>
                    <input name="customerdistance" type="hidden" id="customerdistance" value=""/>


        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Delivery Address</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Billing Address</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="tab-1">
                    <h1>Delivery Address</h1>
                    <p id="deliverystatus" style="color: red;"></p><p>We've automatically filled in your credit card billing address, but if it's different, please amend your details using the Billing Address tab.</p><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">What time would you like your order delivered?</label><select name="requested_time" class="form-control"><option value="17:10:00">17:10:00</option><option value="17:20:00">17:20:00</option><option value="17:30:00">17:30:00</option><option value="17:40:00">17:40:00</option><option value="17:50:00">17:50:00</option><option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option><option value="18:10:00">18:10:00</option><option value="18:20:00">18:20:00</option><option value="18:30:00">18:30:00</option><option value="18:40:00">18:40:00</option><option value="18:50:00">18:50:00</option><option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option><option value="19:10:00">19:10:00</option><option value="19:20:00">19:20:00</option><option value="19:30:00">19:30:00</option><option value="19:40:00">19:40:00</option><option value="19:50:00">19:50:00</option><option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option><option value="20:10:00">20:10:00</option><option value="20:20:00">20:20:00</option><option value="20:30:00">20:30:00</option><option value="20:40:00">20:40:00</option><option value="20:50:00">20:50:00</option></select>      </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="firstnames" id="deliveryfirstnames" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label class="control-label">Surname</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" id="deliverysurname" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label class="control-label">Address Line 1</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="address1" id="deliveryaddress1" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="address2" id="deliveryaddress2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">City </label>
                        <input value="Belfast" class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="deliverycity" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Postcode </label>
                        <input value="" class="form-control" type="text" name="postcode" id="deliverypostcode" title="Please enter a valid Northern Ireland postcode" pattern="[BT|bt][BT|bt]\d{1,2}\s?\d[A-Z|a-z][A-Z|a-z]" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Phone </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control" type="tel" name="phonenumber" id="deliveryphonenumber" title="Enter your full phone number if you are entering a landline number" maxlength="11" pattern="\d{11}" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Email </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control" type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Comments </label>
                        <input type="textarea"  name="customercomments" placeholder="Any comments, e.g. delivery information"/><br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane " role="tabpanel" id="tab-2">
                    <h1>Credit Card Billing Address</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="billingfirstnames" id="firstnames" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Surname</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="billingsurname" id="surname" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Address Line 1</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="billingaddress1" id="billingaddress1" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="billingaddress2" id="billingaddress2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">City </label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="billingcity" id="billingcity" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                        <select name="billingcountry" class="form-control">
                            <option value="GB" selected>United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="IE">Republic of Ireland</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Postcode </label>
                        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="billingpostcode" id="billingpostcode" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Phone </label>
                        <input  class="form-control form-control" type="tel" name="billingphonenumber" id="billingphonenumber" title="Enter your full phone number including 02890 if you are entering a landline number" maxlength="11" pattern="\d{11}" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </form>
    </div>



       <script type="text/javascript">
    //   $(document).ready(function() { 
    //  $("#sageform").submit(function(e){
    //      e.preventDefault();
    //  });
 //  });

    $("#deliveryfirstnames").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#firstnames").val(value);
    }).keyup();

     $("#deliverysurname").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#surname").val(value);
    }).keyup();

     $("#deliveryaddress1").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#billingaddress1").val(value);
    }).keyup();

     $("#deliveryaddress2").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#billingaddress2").val(value);
    }).keyup();

     $("#deliverycity").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#billingcity").val(value);
    }).keyup();

     $("#deliverypostcode").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#billingpostcode").val(value);
    }).keyup();

    $("#deliveryphonenumber").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        value=value.replace(/\s/g,'');
        $(this).val(value);
        $("#billingphonenumber").val(value);
    }).keyup();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

//  $(document).ready(function () {
//      $('#sageform').validator()
//              $('#sageform').submit(function (e) {
//                  $('#sageform').validator('validate');
//                  console.log("validating");
//               });
//            });



//      $('#sageform').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
//      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
//      // handle the invalid form...
//      } else {
//      // if delivery
// //       checkForDelivery(\'pay\')
// //       else
// //       document.forms[\'sageform\'].submit()
//      // everything looks good!
//      }
// });

//  var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

//    $.fn.validator.Constructor.FOCUS_OFFSET = navHeight;

//    console.log(navHeight);
</script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  It appears it was because I had put my opening `form` tag up in the navbar so my button would be within the form.  I tried moving the opening `form` tag to immediately above the first `<div class="form-group">` and it is now working!